# WebBrowser.Document is null on return from thread

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I'm currently trying to do some webscraping using this code:

```
public static User registerUser()
    {
        User toreturn = new User();

        string csrf;

        WebBrowser webcontrol = new WebBrowser();

        webcontrol.AllowNavigation = true;
        webcontrol.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        webcontrol.Navigate("https://example.com/signup");
        webcontrol.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webcontrol_DocumentCompleted);

        HtmlElementCollection forms = webcontrol.Document.GetElementById("csrf_token").GetElementsByTagName("value");

        string tosend = forms[0].InnerText;
        toreturn.apikey = tosend;
        return toreturn;
    }

    private static void webcontrol_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

However, the entire variable webcontrol.Document is null, both before and after the event.

Any idea as to why this is? Hard to scrape when blind.

EDIT: Worth noting, obviously I need to use the values I get

OK

So now I have got it to load thanks to help below, but I can't get the threads to return the value..

```
public static User registerUser()
    {
        Uri test = new Uri("https://www.example.com/signup");
        HtmlDocument testdoc = runBrowserThread(test);

        string tosend = "test";

        User user = new User();

        user.apikey = tosend;

        return user;

    }
    public static HtmlDocument runBrowserThread(Uri url)
    {
        HtmlDocument value = null;
        var th = new Thread(() =>
        {
            var br = new WebBrowser();
            br.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
            br.Navigate(url);
            value = br.Document;
            Application.Run();
        });
        th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        th.Start();
        th.Join(8000); 
        return value;
    }

    static void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var br = sender as WebBrowser;
        if (br.Url == e.Url)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Natigated to {0}", e.Url);
            Console.WriteLine(br.Document.Body.InnerHtml);
            System.Console.ReadLine();
            Application.ExitThread();   // Stops the thread
        }
    }
```

The System.Console.WriteLine works - I see the HTML! Joy! (Although its cloudflare, but I should get whitelisted)

But the thread returns null..

Comment: In your code, you are possibly accessing `webcontrol.Document` before the event fires. Is `webcontrol.Document` indeed null in the body of `webcontrol_DocumentCompleted`?

Comment: Hmm doesn't seem to trigger..

Comment: Is it triggered if you assign the webcontrol_DocumentCompleted handler before calling Navigate? If yes, try accessing the Document in the handler.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't seem to work either:

`public static void registerUser()
        {

            WebBrowser webcontrol = new WebBrowser();

            webcontrol.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webcontrol_DocumentCompleted);
            webcontrol.Navigate("https://coinkite.com/signup");
        }

        private static void webcontrol_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(((WebBrowser)sender).Document);
            System.Console.ReadLine();

        }`

Comment: Is this a console app? Check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720703/webbrowser-doesnt-get-to-documentcompleted-event

Comment: FWIW I was able to reproduce exactly what @SzabolcsDézsi is referring to. If I run the message pump with Application.Run, it works. (I assume the WebBrowser control is a `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`)

Comment: So how would I return the response from the thread?

Comment: Added source to top for clarity